Terminals won't start a shell sometimes, cannot log out
Since upgrading to Sequoia 15.1.1, I have this curious problem that after many days or weeks of operation, neither Terminal nor iTerm2 will launch a shell when opening a new tab, window, or starting the application, no matter what shell is configured in preferences. The window just stays blank and does not react to Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Z.


Sampling the Terminal process doesn't reveal anything to me
Call graph:
    2481 Thread_15593928   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
    + 2481 start  (in dyld) + 2840  [0x19a878274]
    +   2481 NSApplicationMain  (in AppKit) + 888  [0x19e7d5364]
    +     2481 -[NSApplication run]  (in AppKit) + 480  [0x19e7feae0]
    +       2481 -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]  (in AppKit) + 688  [0x19f14be0c]
    +         2481 _DPSNextEvent  (in AppKit) + 660  [0x19e80ba08]
    +           2481 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter  (in HIToolbox) + 76  [0x1a6155eb8]
    +             2481 ReceiveNextEventCommon  (in HIToolbox) + 636  [0x1a6155d54]
    +               2481 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode  (in HIToolbox) + 292  [0x1a614ff64]
    +                 2481 CFRunLoopRunSpecific  (in CoreFoundation) + 588  [0x19acdfbc4]
    +                   2481 __CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 1212  [0x19ace073c]
    +                     2481 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort  (in CoreFoundation) + 160  [0x19ace1edc]
    +                       2481 mach_msg  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 24  [0x19abba17c]
    +                         2481 mach_msg_overwrite  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 480  [0x19abc29d8]
    +                           2481 mach_msg2_internal  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 80  [0x19abcc5d0]
    +                             2481 mach_msg2_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x19abb9e34]
    2481 Thread_15593934
    + 2481 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x19abf60f0]
    +   2481 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 364  [0x19abf7424]
    +     2481 __workq_kernreturn  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x19abbba84]
    2481 Thread_15593935
    + 2481 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x19abf60f0]
    +   2481 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 364  [0x19abf7424]
    +     2481 __workq_kernreturn  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x19abbba84]
    2481 Thread_15593940: com.apple.terminal.low-disk-space-handler
    + 2481 thread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x19abf60fc]
    +   2481 _pthread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 136  [0x19abfb2e4]
    +     2481 __NSThread__start__  (in Foundation) + 724  [0x19be98734]
    +       2481 ???  (in Terminal)  load address 0x102ed0000 + 0x4c9c  [0x102ed4c9c]
    +         2481 kevent  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x19abbfefc]
    2481 Thread_15593946
    + 2481 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x19abf60f0]
    +   2481 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 364  [0x19abf7424]
    +     2481 __workq_kernreturn  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x19abbba84]
    2481 Thread_15593947: com.apple.terminal.sigchld-handler
    + 2481 thread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x19abf60fc]
    +   2481 _pthread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 136  [0x19abfb2e4]
    +     2481 __NSThread__start__  (in Foundation) + 724  [0x19be98734]
    +       2481 ???  (in Terminal)  load address 0x102ed0000 + 0xc18c  [0x102edc18c]
    +         2481 read  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x19abba9b0]
    2481 Thread_15593950: com.apple.terminal.tty-io
    + 2481 thread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x19abf60fc]
    +   2481 _pthread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 136  [0x19abfb2e4]
    +     2481 __NSThread__start__  (in Foundation) + 724  [0x19be98734]
    +       2481 ???  (in Terminal)  load address 0x102ed0000 + 0xd260  [0x102edd260]
    +         2481 __select  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x19abc4e9c]
    2481 Thread_15593951: com.apple.NSEventThread
      2481 thread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x19abf60fc]
        2481 _pthread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 136  [0x19abfb2e4]
          2481 _NSEventThread  (in AppKit) + 148  [0x19e930b8c]
            2481 CFRunLoopRunSpecific  (in CoreFoundation) + 588  [0x19acdfbc4]
              2481 __CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 1212  [0x19ace073c]
                2481 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort  (in CoreFoundation) + 160  [0x19ace1edc]
                  2481 mach_msg  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 24  [0x19abba17c]
                    2481 mach_msg_overwrite  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 480  [0x19abc29d8]
                      2481 mach_msg2_internal  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 80  [0x19abcc5d0]
                        2481 mach_msg2_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x19abb9e34]

Furthermore, I cannot log out of the desktop. The applications quit, but nothing further happens. When opening an app again, I get presented with a popup informing me that logout was interrupted.

How can I figure out what the problem is? So far I have always had to reboot to fix the problem, sometimes force reboot due to the aformentioned logout problem.

Can you still launch other applications at that time?

What shell?  What do you have in that shell's init?  Your example iTerm looks like the shell init is trying to run something with sudo.
